# Duplicate generator sequence hibernate on subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I follow this post to resolve my initial problem:
[Specifying distinct sequence per table in Hibernate on subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560813/specifying-distinct-sequence-per-table-in-hibernate-on-subclasses)

But now I get an exception:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate generator name idgen

Below my class, subclass and pom.xml:

**EntityId (abstract class)**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityId<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1974679434867091670L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="idgen", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="id")
    protected T id;

    public T getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**Category class**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="idgen", sequenceName="cat_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="id", column = @Column(name="cat_id"))
})
@Table(name="categoria")
public class Category extends EntityId<Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -870288485902136248L;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

}
```

pom.xml

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
...
```

My problem it's similar with this post: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12329

Comment: And there is an answer for your question `A sequence generator may be specified on the entity class or on the primary key field or property. The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit (across all generator types).` more details in comments under referenced [link](A sequence generator may be specified on the entity class or on the primary key field or property. The scope of the generator name is global to the persistence unit (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12329#comment-101325).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the link you provided. The JPA spec says that:

> A sequence generator may be specified on the entity class or on the
>   primary key field or property. The scope of the generator name is
>   global to the persistence unit (across all generator types).

So, it's not legal to have two identifier generators with the same name and different configurations. The scope is global, not entity.

To resolve your issue you should push the @Id from the @MappedSuperclass into subclasses.

[More details](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12329)

---

Edited, added possible workaround:

- remove annotation from field in super class;
- make getter abstract;
- let all sub-classes have their own sequence generator: all generators should have global unique name;
- implement getter;
- move annotations related to Id field on getter.

---

```
public interface EntityId<T extends Serializable> extends Serializable {

    public T getId();

    public void setId(T id);

}

@Entity
@Table(name="categoria")
public class Category implements EntityId<Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -870288485902136248L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="cat_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="cat_id_gen", sequenceName="categoria_cat_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="cat_id_gen", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    //others attributes here...

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, but he isn't explain about the "push the \@Id from the \@MappedSuperClass into subclasses", following the ask made by Stefan Mueller: "Hi Vlad, what do you mean by pushing the \@Id?". Not make a sense duplicate the property id in my subclass.

Comment: And the JPA spec says too: "String name (Required) A unique generator name that can be referenced by
one or more classes to be the generator for primary key values."

Comment: First, about push down, it means move the field to subclasses. [Great explanation and example](https://refactoring.guru/push-down-field) Some IDE can help you to do it automatically, for example Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Second, you want same field in all sub classes. But you want different behavior for some of them. This is a good sign to push down. A possible workaround added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for helped! I will try another way. As soon as possible I post my feedback here.

Comment: Your last edit is similiar that I trying here, but without push down the id. I will try implement and test today.

Comment: I testing just now. I will edit your post, just implement and put the annotations on getter not work, occur this exception: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: *Category

Comment: Works well in Spring boot 2.0.3 and hibernate 5.2.17.final