# Duplicate generator name warning when using base entity in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In a Java (Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA) app, use a basic entity and build the inheritance as shown below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CookBase extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cook_base_gen")
    private long id;

    // other fields
}
```

The following entities are inheriting from base entity:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "cook_base_gen", sequenceName = "curb_side_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class CurbSide extends CookBase {

    public CurbSide(@NotNull UUID groupUuid, @NotNull String name) {
        super(groupUuid, name);
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "cook_base_gen", sequenceName = "room_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Room extends CookBase {

    public Room(@NotNull UUID groupUuid, @NotNull String name) {
        super(groupUuid, name);
    }
}
```

When running the app, I get the following warning on the console:

> Duplicate generator name cook_base_gen 
> Duplicate generator name cook_base_gen

I think there may be a mistake regarding to the configuration of inheritance, but `@SequenceGenerator(name = "cook_base_gen", sequenceName = "room_id_seq")` seems ok I think. Any idea?

Comment: Hi! First of all, where did you defined the ```dining_base_gen``` generator? Your code does not contain that string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate generator sequence hibernate on subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516224/duplicate-generator-sequence-hibernate-on-subclasses)

Comment: @y434y Sorry, I updated error as "*cook_base_gen*".

Comment: @y434y First I will check that answer and inform you, but before I inform, please do not close the question. regards

Comment: I checked, but there are different workaround suggestion. At first, it suggests "*pushing the @Id from the MappedSuperclass into subclasses.*". In this case, would it be enough **to push the Id from the CookBase class into subclasses (CurbSide and Room)** enough? Or do I need to follow the other workarounds mentioned on that page?

Comment: @y434y Any reply please?

Comment: I would try to push @Id annotation to according fields defined in subclasses and then - if it does not help - try other ways.

Comment: @y434y I just find time to try and I think there is no need to push Id field. Instead, I try to remove `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cook_base_gen")` from base entity. Then, update `@SequenceGenerator` fields as `@SequenceGenerator(name = "curb_side_gen", sequenceName = "curb_side_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)` and `@SequenceGenerator(name = "room_gen", sequenceName = "room_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)` respectively. Now I get "** Schema-validation: missing sequence [`hibernate_sequence`]**" error. What about this approach and the cause of error? Any idea?