# How to solve problem with common auto_increment id for all tables

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have many tables, but they have common auto increment. For example, I create my first user it has id 1, then I create a message it has id 2, then I create a comment to message and it has id 3 but it should have id = 1 cause I don't have any other comments or messages

My user:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

//    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
//    private List<Message> messages;

//    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
//    private List<Comment> comments;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gender_id")
    private Gender gender;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_subscriptions",
            joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id") ,
            inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id"))
    private Set<User> subscribers;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_subscriptions",
            joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id") ,
            inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id"))
    private Set<User> subscriptions;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    private FileEntity fileEntity;

}
```

My message:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "tag")
    private String tag;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;

    @Column(name = "header")
    private String header;

    @Column(name = "like_count")
    private Integer likeCount = 0;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "message_likes",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "message_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}
    )
    private Set<User> likes;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id")
    private FileEntity fileEntity;


}
```

My comment:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "header")
    private String header;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "like_count")
    private Integer likeCount = 0;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User author;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private Message message;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "comment_likes",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}
    )
    private Set<User> likes;
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `AUTO` generation strategy of hibernate is `SEQUENCE`, which creates and uses *one common database sequence for all entities*.

To get the behavior you want, you can specify a dedicated sequence for each table, e.g. as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561233
Note that hibernate may be configured to reserve multiple IDs at once for performance reasons, so even with a dedicated sequence per entity, there might still be gaps in the IDs.

---

To reduce the setup effort (and the chance of having ID gaps), you could also switch to `IDENTITY`, which internally also creates and uses a dedicated sequence for the table. However, the entity id is then only assigned upon insert, so there are possible perfomance drawbacks (since hibernate cannot delay the inserts e.g. until the end of a transaction).

https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/